# Adding a class to the model folder

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently learning MVC 5 and am using the IDE Visual Studio, I am a complete beginner in MVC I do know C sharp to an decent level though.

The tutorial I am following has added a class to the model folder but when I tried to do so the button to add a class is grey so you cannot select it.

What do I do?

[image]

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: Quite unusual issue, could you provide the screenshot and give a little bit more info, otherwise as @DavidG said your question is too broad?

Comment: Do you mean you right-clicked the project's Model folder, and there is no Add > Class available/enabled?

Comment: Are you trying to do this while your project is still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model classes cannot be added when the project on Visual studio is still debugging. Hence to add a model class, or make any changes you must click the `stop debugging` button.

Answer (score 8):

The project was being debugged in Visual Studio. When the site is running in Visual Studio things like model classes, controllers, etc. cannot be added.

Comment: we already answered the question in the comments above so your answer wasn't necessary but is appreciated.

Comment: @NafisRahman: This was posted as a community wiki, so the question would show has having been answered. I don't get any credit for it; it's just for the sake of keeping SO clean. In the future, if your comment answers the question, then post it as an answer, not a comment.